# how to handle special character “_” in below code

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error on below code. my output contain special character "" previous the out is like with out special character "" FC201780 then no issue. if the data come with special character "_" then im getting issue like

Input string was not in a correct format issue.

```
     DataTable dtBordNo = new DataTable();
                    dtBordNo = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "BordNo");
                    var stringArr = dtBordNo.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("BordNo")).ToArray();

                    string start, end;
                    string result = string.Empty;
                    end = start = stringArr[0];

                    for (int i = 1; i < stringArr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(stringArr[i].Substring(3, stringArr[i].Length - 3)) == (Convert.ToInt32(stringArr[i - 1].Substring(3, stringArr[i - 1].Length - 3)) + 1))
                        {
                            end = stringArr[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (start == end)
                                result += start + ",";
                            else
                                result += start + "-" + end + ",";

                            start = end = stringArr[i];
                        }
                    }
```

Previous output with no issue : FC201780 and expect output with issue : FC_20_1780

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65772584/how-to-handle-special-character-in-below-code?noredirect=1#comment116292393_65772584 ?

Comment: Also, I doubt you are really using C# 2.0, which is 16 years old. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions

Comment: "_" is not a legal character for an integer. So that's totally expected. Sanitize your input.

Comment: I see no `_` character in the code provided.

Comment: It's in the data, @OlivierRogier. "FC_20_1780"

Comment: @Teja What is `stringArr` ? It seems you try to convert non integer string value... Can you provide a sample, please ? Also you should use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to get control over convert errors.

Comment: stringArr[0]; it us an array , actually when I receive data as FC_20_1780 I'm getting conversion error. as  Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: @Teja _" I'm getting conversion error. as Input string was not in a correct format"_ - yes. Because it isn't. Obviously. "`_`" is not a valid char in an integer. You cannot convert something that contains "`_`" to an integer. What do you want to happen if there _is_ a "_"?

Comment: if there is a "_" then condition should pass. I need complete string value with "_"

Comment: Then you need to sanitize that string for conversion, only.

Comment: can you please tell me how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you cannot mutate the original string.

So, I'd suggest to create a conversion-method like this:

```
private int ConverToInt( string intAsString )
{
    string sanitized = intAsString.Replace("_", "");
    return int.Parse(sanitized);
}
```

In addition, I'd also suggest to have a function

```
private string Snip(string original)
{
     // TODO check if original.Length > 6, decide what to do if it fails.
    return original.Substring(3, original.Length - 3)
}
```

just for readablity and then replace

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(stringArr[i].Substring(3, stringArr[i].Length - 3)) == (Convert.ToInt32(stringArr[i - 1].Substring(3, stringArr[i - 1].Length - 3)) + 1))
```

with

```
if ( ConvertToInt(Snip(stringArr[i])) == (ConvertToInt(Snip(stringArr[i - 1])) + 1) )
```

**for starters**.

### EDIT

I just realized, the index may become messed up by sanitation, so you may want to combine both suggested functions as such:

```
private int GetIntValue( string input )
{ 
    string sanitized = input.Replace("_", "");
    sanitized = sanitized.Substring(3, sanitized.Length - 3)
    return int.Parse(sanitized);
}
```

and then just do

```
if ( GetIntValue(stringArr[i]) == (GetIntValue(stringArr[i - 1]) + 1) )
```